# android SDK manager, only show installed package

Tags: android, sdk

There is something wrong with my SDK manager, which only show the installed package. I couldn't install the others.

*I downloaded the ADT bundle for windows from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know why? Thx!

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried running the SDK Manager with `Run as Administrator`?

It always fails loading or downloading packages for me when it isn't ran as an admin.

Comment: Yes, that means 'show installed packages too'. But he has the 'Updates/New' checked, and that means 'show not installed packages and packages with updates available'. For example, here is [my SDK manager's screenshot](http://habrastorage.org/storage2/8d0/abd/dc8/8d0abddc8564fe013e19931e729e4ebd.png)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and its about proxy issues I think. To solve it: in SDK manager go to 
Tools > options 
In other section check the below:
force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...

Then it will fetch all the packages!

Answer (score 3):

I often get **temporary** connection errors on the dl-ssl.google.com repo site. To determine if it's a simple connectivity issue, you could attempt to connect to [one of the repo file links](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml) via your browser.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me -[image]

Keep HTTP proxy server and HTTP proxy port empty `(from Tools -> option)`
and check force https

Comment: Force https is the solution

Answer (score 1):

Manager is unable to load list of packages from repository, probably it's proxy or firewall issue (as I know, it uses standard http). So, it just doesn't know anything about non-installed packages.

Check your internet connection and try again (there is a button "Reload" in the "Packages" menu)

Answer (score 1):

You can download only SDK here: http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r22.0.5-windows.exe
and install all use this.

Answer (score 0):

Check my solution on this issue. You may need to use a Proxy to connect to the internet then attempt your download. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673234/titanium-studio-mac-os-10-9-android-sdk-manager-not-fetching-packages?noredirect=1#comment41947077_26673234)

I believe this should solve your problem, seemingly your having connection issues.