# Why Android SDK Manager only show default packages?

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I have install Eclipse and Adroid SDK on ubuntu and i can only see installed packages , i have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169816/android-sdk-manager-only-show-installed-package) question but my sdk manager show me no error or any thing else.How can i fix it or install theme manually ? what did i do wrong ?

the log is :

```
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-9.xml
Done loading packages.
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-9.xml
Done loading packages.
```

I add some link in User Defined Sites but nothing apear by this log:

```
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-9.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear-sys-img.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/mips/sys-img.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sys-img.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
Done loading packages.
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-9.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear-sys-img.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/mips/sys-img.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sys-img.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
Done loading packages.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Google blocks some IP addresses. My IP was in that list, so I used a proxy to get through it. You can set it by using SDK Manager-> Menu -> Option.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the following Official Add-on Sites (You can find this under Tools -> Manage Add On Sites). Maybe some are disabled for you?

[image: Add On Sites]

Edit:

Maybe you've only enabled "Show Installed Packages" located under Packages?

Comment: Thanks, this is in Windows,i have Linux,anyway this list is empty for me.as you know we can't modify this list.

Comment: No i don't enabled "Show Installed Packages".

Comment: You could try to add them under "User Defined Sites". As far as I know these are multi-platform Repos

Comment: Under Packages I've enabled "Show Updated/New Packages", "Show Installed Packages"

Comment: I update question with user define site and enable all to show everything, nothing show.

Comment: You could try re downloading the SDK, if nothing else helps.

Comment: I re downloaded it but nothing happens.Am i the only one with this problem in the world :) ?