# Titanium Studio Mac OS 10.9 Android SDK Manager not fetching Packages

Tags: android, macos, titanium, android-sdk-manager

Can someone help or direct me in the right path? I am at a predicament. I believe my issue has something to do with my internet connection being filtered sine i am not in North America at the moment. System Specifications and issue:

Installed: Titanium Studio 3.4.0

OS: Mac OS 10.9.5 Mavericks

Titanium SDK default path: /Users/"name"/Library/Application Support/Titanium/ (has a folder labled 'sdk' and 'mobilesdk' in it)

Android SDK default path: /Users/"name"/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/android-sdk-macos

As you can see in the first picture below, the loaded packages do not show most options to download (as i have seen other peoples manager lists and they populate with all kinds of packages). I dont even have the Google API and I am having an error in Titanium Studio. It calims my Android SDK is missing Google API 10+ addon (Items Required: Add-On addon.+google.+apis.+[10]).

I have downloaded the latest "adt" bundle for Mac and the 'android-sdk-macos' SDK from developer.google.com. Please help me resolve why I can't seem to get the list of packages to show Google3 API so I can download it and finaly start using Studio.

Side note: I am having trouble launching the defualt imported Geocoder project on ios simulator. It erros out and says "TypeError: Invalid Version: android-sdk-macos.0.0". (See Platform Configuration picture below for version details i am running)

[image: My Android SDK Manager Window on my Mac OS 10.9]

[image: My PLatform Configuration window on Titanium Studio 3.4.0 on Mac OS 10.9]

P.S. I believe my issue is that my Internet is being filtered and i generally require a vpn connection to connect to http://developer.google.com (since otherwise it claims it is not available to my country). When the Android SDK Manager runs, the initial `Fetching packages: http:/ /dll-google...'` connection isn't going through, seemingly. To be exact, I am in Asia, and the internet here gets filtered. i have attempted to run this (Android SDK Manager) through a VPN connection and yet still, the packages don't appear (as one would expect). Any suggestions?

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22338289/3419997)

Comment: Thanks turtle, however, it still didn't solve my issue. I even attempted the "Force https://" method. Good try though.

Answer (score 1):

Behold, I was being filtered. I got around this by going to a proxy site list: [Free Proxy](http://letushide.com/filter/https,all,all/list_of_free_HTTPS_proxy_servers) and set my Proxy Setting on my Mac OS as such (see picture below). I am running a VMWare Virtual Machine Mac OS and this still works (for those running a VM with similar issue). The IP address I used for the HTTPS proxy setting did it, because the connection to https//:google gets refused by Google end (due to my country). HTTPS proxy setting for you might differ, always use fresh HTTPS IP address (see link above).

See second picture of the SDK after it fetches the list when HTTPS Proxy is set. It is a much more extensive list and confirms the IP filtering. Note that the first IP address I tried for the proxy let me download a few items. I had to use consequent IP address to downlaod all the packages I wanted as the proxies sometiems would fail to resolve the host "fetch" HTTPS address on the SDK Manager.

Thanks for you'r views, hope this helps someone out there.

[image: Mac Os Proxy Settings]
[image: Android SDK Manager (Proxy enabled Network connection)]