# Android-sdk manager is not showing all Packages

Tags: android, android-studio, java-7, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

I have a problem , my android-sdk-manager is suddenly stopped showing all packages, it is only showing the installed packages only. Can you guys help me out how to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate through File --> setting --> Android SDK --> SDK update site tab, in that check  **force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...**

[image]

Comment: did you got all packages now ?@Dead-Archie

Comment: No, force https://... sources to be fetched using http://... is check. but not getting all packages.

Comment: have you tried checking/unchecking box of Updates/New OR Installed in Android SDK Manager Window ?

Comment: Yes i have also tried that, toggled Updates/New OR Installed check box for 5 mins or more. but nothing happen.

Comment: okay. i thing if you reset android-studio settings than it will work(take backup)

Comment: Yes i did that also, but it is fetching it's previous set up. Can you tell me how to complete delete android settings ?? Which folders need to be deleted ?

Comment: close android-studio than delete C:\Users\dead-archie, now delete .AndroidStudio2.1. inform me if not done.

Comment: Nope, nothing happening, is it be any proxy issue ?

Comment: check answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169816/android-sdk-manager-only-show-installed-package

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, just try toggling "`Updates/New`", there might be a glitch on the SDK manager itself.

Secondly you can go to "`Tools -> Manage Add On sites...`"

[image: Add on sites]

Ensure they are all clicked

Third, try Reloading. i.e "`Packages -> Reload`"

Also check what is ticked with the Packages menu.

Alternatively @[scottt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2825864/scottt) has suggested the following:

> I often get **temporary** connection errors on the dl-ssl.google.com repo site. To determine if it's a simple connectivity issue, you could attempt to connect to [one of the repo file links](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml) via your browser.

Original Post: [android SDK manager, only show installed package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25302823/4180965)

Consider unticking `"Force https://...sources to be fetched using http://..."`, this might cause authentication issues as well.

Comment: there is no 'Manage Add On sites' in/under Tools in new version